# Change Root of MemoryStore not working

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

Possible Duplicate: [How to set url and root dynamically in extjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646944/how-to-set-url-and-root-dynamically-in-extjs)

Hi there, I have a simple memoryStore. If I tried not to declare its proxy during the Ext.Define, I am unable to retrieve the proper data root later on, even if I do set the proxy. Am I doing something wrong?

Here's a test case:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'JailNames',
    autoLoad: true,
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'name',
            type: 'string'
        },
    ],
    data: {
        data_regionI: [
                    {name: "Jail 1"},
                    {name: "Jail 2"},
                    {name: "Jail 3"},
        ],
        data_regionII: [
                    {name: "Jail 4"},
                    {name: "Jail 5"},
                    {name: "Jail 6"},
        ],
    },
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data_regionI'
        }
    }
})



  store.setProxy({
          type: 'memory',
          reader: {
              type: 'json',
              root: 'data_regionII'
          }
      } )

store.load();
store.getAt(0).raw //still returns Jail 1
```

Looking through `store.getProxy().reader.root` I get the data_regionII as a root. Why?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I copy your code into a sencha fiddle  of Version 4.1.1, it throws an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'raw' of undefined`, which is what I expected, because the store shouldn't contain any records at all after the call to `load()`.

There are many problems in your understanding what a store does and what a proxy does:

- A normal store's `load` function will tell the proxy to fetch the data, tell the reader to make records from it, and load it into the `data` property of your store, overwriting(!) the data you have defined at initialization.
- But a memory store's load function isn't intended to do anything at all, and isn't intended to be used at all.
- A memory store isn't intended to hold more than one store content at the same time. (you can, however, store the unused contents in an *unused*(!) property of the store's JavaScript object).
- A store, no matter which proxy, does not require `autoLoad:true` to load the content of `data` into the store - the content of `data` is automatically used as the default data of the store after initialization.

That said, it's still possible to achieve what you want with just a few lines of code. You don't even have to create all the functions I only made for readability:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'JailNames',
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'name',
            type: 'string'
        },
    ],
    myData: { // custom property!
        data_regionI: [
                    {name: "Jail 1"},
                    {name: "Jail 2"},
                    {name: "Jail 3"},
        ],
        data_regionII: [
                    {name: "Jail 4"},
                    {name: "Jail 5"},
                    {name: "Jail 6"},
        ],
    },
    loadRegion1:function() {
        this.loadRegion("data_regionI");
    },
    loadRegion2:function() {
        this.loadRegion("data_regionII");
    },
    loadRegion:function(rootProperty) { // custom function for better readability
        this.loadRawData(this.myData[rootProperty]); // load data without proxy, but with reader!
    },
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
});
store.loadRegion1();
console.log(store.getAt(0).get("name")); //returns Jail 1
store.loadRegion2();
console.log(store.getAt(0).get("name")); //returns Jail 4
```

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification, Alexander! I understand what you meant by this. Ups for you!